# How to create a file using task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, task, scheduler

I have a bat file that starts a service, and it's scheduled in the [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). I used the psexec command for that. I want to add another trigger based on the event, the event being completion of the "start the service" (aforementioned) to create a .txt file on a remote server or the local server whichever is possible.

Answer (score 3):

By default a file created in c:\Windows\System32\ (Windows 10)

Set full path to file in a batch file, for example

```
echo > c:\temp\myfilename.txt
```

Or set the path in a "Start in (optional)" field on "Actions" tab of task properties in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a text file out with a batch script is as easy as echo'ing it out.

```
echo > myfilename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan briansol, I have to open a new .txt file and rename it as sometest.bat file and in it paste echo > myfilename.txt. Once done click on the bat file to execute it and create the file myfilename.txt, is that correct?

Comment: yup, that should work, assuming the executor user id has write permissions to that folder.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions